# to retrieve the Name , Host and SessionId of the of the users with TOP 10 maximum of sessionIds in a particular time

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

> Here is the source Table . I want to retrieve the Name , Host and
>   SessionId of the of the users with TOP 10  maximum of sessionIds in a
>   particular time
>
> Example
>
> Host          Name           SessionId   NoOfSessionsOpen
>    ( 10.42.64.79 ,   thidrat.xyz   ,  tkj7j    ,    4 )

Comment: Could you please provide example of output you'd like to see?

Comment: Maximum regarding what measure? Number of Requests?

Comment: @Trekstuff I have modified the question with output

Comment: @usr Maximum Regarding No of Sessions (id SessionId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 10 Name, Host, SessionID, count(*)
from Table
where TimeLog between @a and @b
group by Name, Host, SessionID
order by count(*) desc, Name, Host, SessionID --define a total sort order for determinism
```